# Problem with Minion Pro

Tags: fonts, minionpro

I have a weird problem with the output using MinionPro fonts. The characters "Th" after a period produces a strange output; for example

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\begin{document}

Testing Minion Pro. The Minion Pro package...

\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

```
Testing Minion Pro. fb e Minion Pro package...
```

Does anybody have a clue of what's happening?

Comment: Everything is fine here, with Lubuntu 11.10 and texlive 2011.

Comment: Which operating system and TeX distribution do you employ?

Comment: Also, possible font size options for `report` are `10pt` (standard), `11pt`, and `12pt`. For more sizes, have a look at the [`extsizes` document classes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/extsizes).

Comment: Thanks for the answers...The OS is WinXP, with MikTeX 2.8 + TexnicCenter.
The weird thing is that in my desktop PC this "problem" does not appear! (the OS is Win 7 with MikTeX 2.9 + TexnicCenter + "fontspec" NOT loaded!). I've also tried with 11 and 12pt...

Comment: Maybe you should update your MikTex to 2.9 then...

Answer (score 1):

I bet this is a an automatic ligature -- th.

[image: Minion Pro Ligatures]

It's just a default feature of the font. It's not an error. You can disable it with fontspec, but I don't think it's desirable.

Comment: But T+h should produce the ligature shown low left on your image, not the ligature for f+b …

Comment: Yes. But you should write this in the answer …

Comment: The fontspec package does not solve the problem.

Comment: I'd like to keep on trying before updating...

Comment: The fontspec SOLVED the problem...My mistake...The line \usepackage[T1]{fontspec} produces the right output. Thanks to everybody!